# I have a problem, which seems with settings.gradle, but i dont know how to fix it, also, it keeps showing red letters for some reason

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

- What went wrong:
  Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/coja/StudioProjects/kuda_ici/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/coja/.gradle/caches/6.7/scripts/f0emg6u6oecmxqzgk5g9nn4ui).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

[This is my settings.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvmUN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clear.` in your terminal

Comment: it says Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

Comment: Can you post the image of your terminal?